# Ruby preloading classes in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a highly modified Rails repository. None of the classes use ActiveRecord. I'm finding that I have to specify many file and gem requirements at the top of each class. I want to have the requirements for each class preloaded in an initializer rather than it being specified in the class. How do I do this? Is this a bad idea? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

The obvious one is to require a single file, and then inside that file have all of your requirements listed.

For example in `list_of_requirements.rb` you could have

```
require 'thin'
require 'x'
require 'y'
```

Then in your  `class_that_requires_stuff.rb` you could have

```
require 'list_of_requirements'
```

This way in your indvidual classes you only need one require statement and you don't need to require all these gems in every file. You also don't need an initializer.

Comment: Thanks. There's one thing you could clear up for me. Pretend in an initializer I had `classes = [User, Post, Comment]` and then I did something like `classes.map{|f| f.require 'gem_x'}`. Because this is in an initializer, it would take a little longer for the app to start up, but I was under the impression that the initializer would pre-load each of those specified class requirements. And I thought this would be faster than each requirement being manually specified in each class and evaluated on runtime. Is this true?     Sorry for the late response.

Comment: When you `require` a gem\file\dll etc it loads it once. If you require it subsequently it uses the in-memory representation, making it pretty quick. You are right though only requiring them when needed may reduce load time, but it also could hide bugs that can only be reproduced when in production. I think generally I would require for everything that is small or has non performance impacting load times, or fix the slow code :)